# username maxlength validation in angular2 is not working with samsung devices. working fine with numeric data but not working with alphanumeric

Tags: angular, ionic2, maxlength

ts code:

imported all the required components.

```
constructor(public platform: Platform, public formBuilder: FormBuilder,public navCtrl: NavController public http: Http) {
this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
  userName: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(16)])),
  password: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(16)]))
  enableTouchId: new FormControl(false, [])
});
}
```

In Html:

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" name="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="login(loginForm)">
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-list no-lines>
        <ion-item class="member-item">
          <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Username"  [readonly]="isReadOnly()" formControlName="userName" name="userName" [(ngModel)]="userName" minlength="5" maxlength="16" required></ion-input>
          <ion-icon ios="ios-person" md="md-person" item-left></ion-icon>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
</form>
```

I have verified/tested the stackoverflow exiting solutions but no luck.

Comment: In a reactive form (which this appears to be) you do not need an `[(ngModel)]` you should instead be getting the form value from the submission `(ngSubmit)`. You are currently mixing reactive and template forms

Answer (score 0):

If you use a FormBuilder with validations you don't need to repeat them on your html, and all you need to identify the input is `formControlName="userName"`, so your html should look like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" name="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="login()">
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-list no-lines>
        <ion-item class="member-item">
          <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Username" [readonly]="isReadOnly()" formControlName="userName"></ion-input>
          <ion-icon ios="ios-person" md="md-person" item-left></ion-icon>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
</form>
```

Then on `login()` you use `this.loginForm` to handle the form.